# Cannot convert to type spring.oxm.marshaller: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, spring-ws

I have been struggling with that error for long time, have googled, looked at the examples around the web and still not getting to work. To be honest I don't understand why my project throws this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller] for property 'marshaller': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
    ... 52 more)
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.fail(TestCase.java:227)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:100)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

So my setup is Spring Web Services, Jaxb2, maven. I have predefined xsd files and generated java classes from them by jaxb2 maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema1-xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>ApplicationResponse.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <packageName>com.package.response</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My pom has additionally these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
    <!-- <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
    <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my appContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.package" />

    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
        <property name="soapVersion">
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
        <property name="defaultUri" value="https://example/address/hidden"/>
        <property name="marshaller" value="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" value="marshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
          <property name="contextPath" value="com.package.request:com.package.request" />
          </bean>
</beans>
```

My service client class

```
@Component
public class NorServiceClient implements NorService {

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate;

    public void setDefaultUri(String defaultUri) {
        wsTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
    }

    public ApplicationResponse downloadFileList(ApplicationRequest request) {
        // Command: DownloadFileList
        return (ApplicationResponse) wsTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
    }
}
```

And my test case:

```
public class AppTest extends TestCase {

    private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/appContext.xml");

    @Test
    public void testApplicationRequest() {
        assertNotNull(new Object());
        System.out.println("Context: " + context);
        NorService norService = (NorService) context.getBean("norServiceClient");
        ApplicationRequest request = new ApplicationRequest();
        nordeaService.downloadFileList(request);
    }
}
```

When launching my app it doesn't even get to the service.downloadFileList, it throws the exception when initializing context. So I don't think it may be the problem that I have instatiated just empty ApplicationRequest object.

Where could the problem lie? By all the examples in the internet I have done setup the same way, but in my project it throws the exception that `no matching editors or conversion strategy found`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your error refers to this

```
<property name="marshaller" value="marshaller" />
```

The property `marshaller` refers to a field of type `org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller` of the class `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate`. You can't give it a String value of `"marshaller"`.

You want to reference another bean in the context with the id `marshaller`.

```
<property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
```

Same thing for your `unmarshaller`.

Comment: Thank you, this error disappeared. Haven't worked with spring XML configuration lately, but because of spring-ws examples were all with xml config, had to go also that way.
Now there is new error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specify either 'contextPath', 'classesToBeBound', or 'packagesToScan'`
That is strange, because 2 of them are defined in my marshaller bean. Where should I define then?

Comment: @Skyzer Does that happen for the `marshaller` bean or for some other component?

Comment: @Sotirious Delimanolis Yes.
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'marshaller' defined in class path resource [appContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specify either 'contextPath', 'classesToBeBound', or 'packagesToScan'`

Comment: It's working now, I had both contextPath and classesToBeBound. Deleted classesToBeBound and now it's working. thank you!